# After deploying to AppHarbor I get The type or namespace name 'WebActivator' could not be found

Tags: appharbor, webactivator

I'm uploading my first application to AppHarbor and I'm getting the following error:

"The type or namespace name 'WebActivator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

The solution is building correctly on the dev environment and on other build servers using MSBuild.

I couldn't find any help on the AppHarbour support page, any idea what could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using NuGet to load the WebActivator package? It is commonly added as a dependency with many nuget packages.

Comment: Chris, I am using NuGet.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command into your nuget:

```
Install-Package WebActivator -version 1.5.3
```

**EDIT**

Here's a link to the [nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebActivatorEx/).

> Install-Package WebActivatorEx

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem in below code:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(
    typeof(myApp.Web.App_Start.BreezeWebApiConfig), "RegisterBreezePreStart")]
```

And I found that in new versions of `WebActivator` its namespace is changed to `WebActivatorEx`; So below code solve my problem:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(
    typeof(myApp.Web.App_Start.BreezeWebApiConfig), "RegisterBreezePreStart")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like WebActivator DLL is not copied to bin folder. Make sure in VS you have Copy Local set to true and that your deployment script includes this file.

You might want to clean your local solution / deployment folder by deleting all instances of WebActivator to try to replicate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for you response. WebActivator.dll is being copy correctly, as I said, it's working fine on other build servers.

Comment: WebActivator loads all the dlls in your bin folder. Maybe AppHarbour doesn't allow file access to bin folder.